# react TypeError: Object.value is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Here is my code which getting user input value and filtering the Countries from Array of objects. Executing this code I am getting an object which filtered correctly(I am getting it in the console of browser)but the problem is that I need to get an string to display it. I have tried  **filterCountry.value** too

```
let matches = Countries.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.value
    ));
console.log(matches);
event.preventDefault();
this.state.eachCountry = matches;

const filterCountries = matches.map((filterCountry) =>
<ul>{filterCountry.toString()}</ul>
);
alert(filterCountries.name);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
`filterCountries` would be an array of jsx  so you can't really do  `.name`

Comment: Dont write html in js but quote it as string : '<ul>'+filterCountry.toString()+'</ul>'

Comment: @Krazibit312 I need to get the value of matches where each object looks like this
    {name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'},

Comment: @Incognito doing like you said I am getting an error. Are you sure that it is correct in react ?

Comment: What line does throw the exception?

Comment: try ```const filterCountries = <ul> 
{ matches.map((filterCountry) =>
<li>{filterCountry.name}</li>}
</ul>```
This would give you a UL list of matched countries

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan, I'm not really sure why you are assigning the result of your filter to `this.state.eachCountry`. If you want to set state, you need 

```javascript
this.setState({eachCounty: matches});
```

Whereas this might not be the fix you're looking for, it's worthy of correction

Comment: @Krazibit312 no it shows red underline

Comment: @Rowland Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {matches}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of

Comment: `const filterCountries = <ul> { matches.map((filterCountry, index) => (<li key={index}>{filterCountry.name}</li>))} </ul>`  edited former to correct some syntax errors

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan, please update your question with a jsfiddle link with mock data to allow the community help you really fast.

Comment: @Rowland here it is https://jsfiddle.net/ArmenSan/05s1mz86/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a react component that shows all the filtered countries in a list you can try something like this:

```
render () {
  const filterCountries = this.state.eachCountry.map((filterCountry) => {
    return (<li>{filterCountry}</li>)
  })
  return (<ul>{filterCountries}</ul>)
}
```

To map an array:

```
Mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Mylist2 = mylist.map ((elem) -> {return elem + 1})
//Then mylist2 = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
```